# How to pass a generic selector Func<T, U> to some method in order to perform search?

Tags: c#, linq, search, lambda

I have a class with some fields.

```
public abstract class RegisteredUser : Transformable //implements interface
{
    protected int id;
    protected bool active;
    protected string name;
    protected string lastName;
    protected string email;
    protected string username;
    protected string password;
    protected int institution;

//OTHER  STUFF FROM  THIS CLASS GO HERE..`
} 
Assistant : RegisteredUser
{
}
```

Once I load all data from .txt file, I'll have a static dictionary like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, Transformable> assistants = null; //this will be filed with objects and their id's
```

Now, my assignment is to achieve functionality of *search* for this console app. Since, all of sub classes will have fields from abstract class, user of this app should have a choice to *search* for any object `Assistant`, `Professor` or `Administrator` by any of its fields.

I would like to achieve this by using `LINQ/lambdas`. My idea is to create some generic method which will accept a *selector* (or some lambda expression ), based on whatever field is being searched for.

I am completely new to LINQ and C# and generally to programming, so I hope that I'm not talking nonsense here.

```
public static List<RegisteredUser> search(Dictionary<int, Transformable> map, 
                                          Func<bool,RegisteredUser> selector, 
                                          Transformable userType)
{
    if (userType is Assistant)
    {
        List<RegisteredUser> list = map.Select(item => (Assistant) item.Value)
                                       .ToList()
                                       .Select(selector)
                                       .ToList();
    }
    //other if/else statements  

    return list;
}
```

Of course, lines in Visual Studio are red :) Basically, I want to be be able send something like 
`user => user.Name.Contains("some string which will be entered by the end user")` to generic function.

Comment: If you want to use `user => user.Name.Contains` it would seem like you want to use `Where` (also in `Linq`) which you want to give a `predicate`. Do you want to have some filtering capacity?

Comment: @aage Yeah, I wanted to wrote Where instead of Select. I want to achieve filtering capacity through that lambda expression, 'user.Name.Contains("some string which will be entered by the end user")'. But, it could have been as well as 'user.Active == true'. I am not sure if I'm explaining correctly, please excuse me, my English is not so great...

Comment: Since you're new to linq, `Select` is like `Map`; you get the same size collection back but of possibly a different type. `Where` is like `Filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to write a separate function to do what you want to achieve, it can all be done with `Linq` directly:

```
var users = new Dictionary<int, Transformable>
{
     {0, new Assistant { Name = "Joe" }},
     {1, new Professor { Name = "John" }},
     {2, new Assistant { Name = "Jane" }}
};

var assistants = users.Values.OfType<Assistant>().Where(a => a.Name == "Jane");
```

`assistants` is an `IEnumerable<Assistant>` with Name equal to "Jane" and will contain only 1 entry from the above dictionary. You could add a ToList() to the end of that to create list alternatively

You can then add whatever predicate you want:

```
var assistants = users.Values.OfType<Assistant>().Where(a => a.Name == "Jane" && a.LastName == "Smith" && a.Active);
```

You could wrap the above in a function but what you'll end up with won't be much shorter than the above.

As an extension method it would be like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(this IEnumerable<Transformable> list, Func<T,bool> predicate) where T :Transformable
    {
        return list.OfType<T>().Where(predicate.Invoke);
    }
}
```

making the call slightly shorter:

```
var assistants = users.Values.Find<Assistant>(a => a.Name == "Jane");
```

This is an example of the fluent API pattern so you can use it in a Linq chain like any other Linq function.

Comment: Make sense, but since I have 8 different fields, I thought to make it more generic. Once I get to GUI part of an app, depending on the listener, I will just pass map and Func<T, bool>. And, I will have few other fields for other subclasses as well. But thank you for making it more clear.

Comment: I've added a function as an extension which you may find useful